# Prevent Duplicate GeoJSON Markers with Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I've made a map using Leaflet.js, where a [control menu](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/) enables a user to select a variety of layers of points that are then plotted on the map based on the criteria (properties) that each point meets.

Problem is, nearly all of these points satisfy the criteria of multiple layers, which leads to the points being plotted at least twice if the user selects at least two overlays from the control that each contain the point in question.

Ideally, I would like each point to only be plotted once, regardless of how many layers it is in that the user selects to be plotted (but of course only as long as it is in at least one layer that has been selected to be plotted).

An example collection of features/points being created in my project is here:

```
let attended = L.geoJSON(guestsJson, {
    filter: attendedFilter,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
  }
)
```

Where `attendedFilter` is:

```
function attendedFilter(feature) {
  if (feature.properties.attended_wedding == true) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

And `onEachFeature()` is here:

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
  // checks if the feature has a property called "popupContent"
  if (feature.properties && feature.properties.popupContent) {
    layer.bindPopup(feature.properties.popupContent);
  }
  layer.on({
    mouseover: highlightFeature,
    mouseout: resetHighlight,
    click: zoomToFeature,
  })
}
```

The link to my lengthy JavaScript file is [here](https://github.com/mgermaine93/wedding-guest-map/blob/master/src/index.js), and the link to the live project itself is [here](https://mgermaine93.github.io/wedding-guest-map/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I finally figured this out.  It's likely not the most efficient way, but it worked for me.  As a reminder, here's what my `guestsJson` variable looks like:

```
let guestsJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "Mr. Groom",
        "state": "Pennsylvania",
        "attended_wedding": true,
        "is_officiant": false,
        "in_wedding_party": true,
        "is_groom": true,
        "is_bride": false,
        "inviter": "Couple",
        "invited": true,
        "is_vendor": false,
        "is_family": true,
        "is_friend": false,
        "is_family_friend": false,
        "is_pre_college_friend": false,
        "is_college_friend": false,
        "is_post_college_friend": false,
        "attended_welcome_party": true,
        "attended_rehearsal_dinner": true,
        "popupContent": "Groom",
        "heardFrom": false
      },
      "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [-80.89294, 41.438918] }
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Here's what I did:

1. Set each "filtered" group to be like this, rather than like I did earlier:

```
let attended = guestsJson.features.filter(function (guest) {
  return guest.properties.attended_wedding
})
```

2. Set dummy GeoJSON values for each of the overlays in the control.

```
// These are all DUMMY values that will be updated with the real values later
let overlayMaps = {
  // Different groups of points go here
  "Church": L.geoJSON(),
  "Everyone": L.geoJSON(),
  "Couple": L.geoJSON(),
  "Invitees": L.geoJSON(),
  "Attendees": L.geoJSON(),
  "Bride's Side": L.geoJSON(),
  "Groom's Side": L.geoJSON(),
  "Couple's Side": L.geoJSON(),
  "Wedding Party": L.geoJSON(),
  "Bride's Family": L.geoJSON(),
  "Groom's Family": L.geoJSON(),
  "Family": L.geoJSON(),
  "Friends": L.geoJSON(),
  "Family Friends": L.geoJSON(),
  "Pre-College Friends": L.geoJSON(),
  "College Friends": L.geoJSON(),
  "Post-College Friends": L.geoJSON(),
  "Rehearsal Dinner Attendees": L.geoJSON(),
  "Welcome Party Attendees": L.geoJSON(),
  "Vendors": L.geoJSON(),
  "Heard From (but not invited)": L.geoJSON()
}
```

3. Created ANOTHER object with key/value pairs similar to the one above, only this time with the ACTUAL "filtered" groups as the values.

```
// THESE ARE THE REAL VALUES FOR THE CONTROL
let geoJsonGroupObject = {
  // Different groups of points go here
  "Church": churchGroup,
  "Everyone": everyone,
  "Couple": couple,
  "Invitees": invited,
  "Attendees": attended,
  "Bride's Side": bridesSide,
  "Groom's Side": groomsSide,
  "Couple's Side": couplesSide,
  "Wedding Party": weddingParty,
  "Bride's Family": bridesFamily,
  "Groom's Family": groomsFamily,
  "Family": family,
  "Friends": friends,
  "Family Friends": familyFriends,
  "Pre-College Friends": preCollegeFriends,
  "College Friends": collegeFriends,
  "Post-College Friends": postCollegeFriends,
  "Rehearsal Dinner Attendees": rehearsalDinnerAttendees,
  "Welcome Party Attendees": welcomePartyAttendees,
  "Vendors": vendors,
  "Heard From (but not invited)": heardFrom
}
```

4. Created the control defining the objects above and added it to the map.

```
// Defines the base open street map view that we see upon page load
let baseMaps = {
  "OpenStreetMap": osm,
}
// sets the control menu in the upper right of the map
let layerControl = L.control.layers(
  baseMaps, 
  overlayMaps, {
    position: 'bottomright',
    collapsed: false
}).addTo(map);
```

5. Captured the layers/overlays that the user has selected thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44322326/how-to-get-selected-layers-in-control-layers):

```
// this helps to tell which overlay layers are checked/plotted on the map
L.Control.Layers.include({
  getActiveOverlays: function() {
    // create a hash to hold all the layers
    let layers = {};
    let control = this;
    // loop through all the layers in the control
    control._layers.forEach(function(obj) {
      let layerName;
      // check if the layer is an overlay
      if (obj.overlay) {
        // get the name of the overlay
        layerName = obj.name;
        // store whether it's present on the map or not
        return layers[layerName] = control._map.hasLayer(obj.layer);
      }
    });
    
    keys = Object.keys(layers)
    
    let activeLayers = keys.filter(function(key) {
      // factors out the layers that don't have any people associated with them
      if (key !== "Church" && key !== "State Outlines") {
        return layers[key]
      }
    })
    return activeLayers;
  }
})
```

6. Then, using the code in Step #5, this is able to do the rest of the work for duplicate detection:

```
// these values are what are ultimately plotted/used on the map
let markerCluster = L.markerClusterGroup()
let parentGroup = L.geoJSON()

// every time an overlay is added or removed, do something
map.on('overlayadd', constructListOfPeopleThatWillBePlottedOnTheMap)
map.on('overlayremove', constructListOfPeopleThatWillBePlottedOnTheMap)

// OKAY, so this function creates a DUPLICATE-FREE list of people features that are ready to be plotted on the map. 
function constructListOfPeopleThatWillBePlottedOnTheMap() {
  
  // removes any existing layers from the predefined markercluster group so that duplicate layers are not plotted
  markerCluster.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    markerCluster.removeLayer(layer)
  })

  // removes any existing layers from the predefined parent group so that duplicate layers are not plotted
  parentGroup.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    parentGroup.removeLayer(layer)
  })

  // constants
  let peopleWhoAreSelectedToBePlotted = []
  let activeLayerNames = layerControl.getActiveOverlays()

  // iterates through the STRING values
  activeLayerNames.forEach(function(layerName) {
    // gets the actual array of objects
    let actualLayerOfPeople = geoJsonGroupObject[layerName]
    // console.log(actualLayerOfPeople)
    actualLayerOfPeople.forEach(function(person) {
      // capture the names that are already in the list to be plotted
      let namesOfPeopleToBePlotted = peopleWhoAreSelectedToBePlotted.map(element => element.properties.name)
      if (namesOfPeopleToBePlotted.includes(person.properties.name)) {
        console.log(person.properties.name)
        console.log("Duplicate detected!")
      }
      else {
        peopleWhoAreSelectedToBePlotted.push(person)
      }
    })
  })

  // adds each feature (each feature represents a person) to the list defined above
  peopleWhoAreSelectedToBePlotted.forEach(function(personFeature) {
    parentGroup.addData(personFeature)
  })

  // binds each popup and adds the entire layer to the markercluster
  parentGroup.eachLayer(function(layer) {
    layer.bindPopup(layer.feature.properties.popupContent)
    markerCluster.addLayer(layer)
  })
  // parentGroup.addTo(map);
  map.addLayer(markerCluster)
}
```

Happily, this does exactly what I wanted it to do.  If you don't want to use markerCluster, it will work for normal GeoJSON markers, too.  You just need to basically swap out the markerCluster references with L.geoJSON ones.

Hope this helps someone -- happy map making!